# NAT: Who will be blamed?

Tags: nat, ip

A computer tries to attack another computer across the Internet. The attacking computer's default gateway applies NAT using some address. The system administrator at that address, notices the attack and makes a complaint. Against which computer will this complaint be made?

Comment: This is not a networking question. You are asking what law will be applied concerning liability. This is then based on the location of your computers/network and the local laws of that locations country.

Comment: You misunderstood the question.

Comment: ok, could you elaborate your question?

Answer (score 3):

Complaints go to the owner of IP addresses, so in this case it will go to the address the person being attacked sees, which is the owner of the NAT gateway. It's up to that owner to handle this further, he's responsible for what his addresses do on the internet.

Comment: true, but on a liability point of view, it's the task of your IT department to make sure virusses and backdoors are scanned for and so on... The firm will be held responsible, not the user of the computer. Well here it is... :)

Comment: He who owns the address (ISP usually) will get the complaint. They can then figure out to whom to delegate that complaint.

Comment: Initially I thought it was in a gray area between on and off topic and decided to answer the question. After some more consideration (and votes/comments from others, yet not enough to close the question) I decided to cast the final vote on it being off topic. I could've removed the question, but since it was deemed useful by some I decided not to do so. In retrospect I probably shouldn't have answered.